# How to manage multilingual content in express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, translation, loopbackjs

I'm building an express app which have to **manage translation** for some fields of my models. (I'm using **loopBackjs** framework to be exact)

**Example**: a product needs to have its **title** and **description** directly editable in the backend form in **multiple languages**

Is there a module that does this kind of translation ?
If not, what is the best way to do this in mongoDB

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sure. I have a loopback product model that have title 
`{
  "name": "product",
  "plural": "products",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "reference": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true,
      "id": true
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
}`

I need to translate title and description. I thought to change title and description to object and store different values like this

`{
   en: 'my product title in english',
   fr: 'mon titre en français'
}`

What do you think ?

Comment: Then my angular app would have the logic to get the value une the right language.

Comment: Yes, that is pretty standard for your problem and works very well for a lot of people.

Comment: ok so i'll do that. Thanks a lot